# Find the least node in a tree

Tags: node.js, vue.js, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel + Vue and I've been stuck in the process of finding the least node in a tree..
This image you will see below is the structure. In one node there must be 3 sub-nodes if he got a 4th one, he, the new node will fill-in in the least sub-nodes below
[IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7cSb.jpg)

I already implemented for the level 3 part but I am struggling on what should I do if ever the new node will fill-in in the least sub-nodes of level 4 nodes and level 5 up to level 7?

Anyone can share their knowledge to work make this work?

here's what I got so far

```
getMemberHasLowestMember(data) {
        // get the lowest number of members count
        let lowest_number_of_members = data.reduce((min, b) => Math.min(min, b.members.length), data[0].members.length)

        // get the members who have the lowest number of members
        let member_has_low_members = data.filter(member => member.members.length == lowest_number_of_members)

        if(member_has_low_members.length > 1) {
          // get the random number from length of members_has_low_members
          let random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(member_has_low_members.length))
          return member_has_low_members[random_number]
        } else {
          return member_has_low_members[0]
        }
},
```

In this case, I have 1 user data and it has `teams` object and in that object it has `members` but as the object go deeper, I still don't know how to get team member's own members until level 7

Comment: Can you show us the code of the tree and what you have done so far?

Comment: Indeed show some code. Now we don't know what you've tried our even if you code it in PHP, JavaScript or maybe even an SQL query. Also explain what you mean with "least" node. Do the nodes have a weight? Anyway, you'll need to create a recursive function to traverse the tree: the function needs to call itself.

Comment: least node meaning the node that has the smallest number of sub-nodes. In one node must only have 3 nodes maximum.

i will try to show the code later when I get back home. THanks!

Comment: @NiklasE.I updated my post with the code.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman I updated my post with the code.